# React doesn't get express session login details sending me 401 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, middleware

I'm trying to make a page that only registered users can access to that page and I'm checking it by middleware at the server side, but when im trying to access the page I get 401 error because the session.user is undefined, while when im trying my code through "postman" it works great without any issues, here is the middleware:

```
function isLoggedIn(request, response, next) {
if (!request.session.user) {
    response.status(401).send("You are not logged in!");
    return;
}
next();
}

module.exports = isLoggedIn;
```

And here is the controller:

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn,async (request, response) => {
try {
    const vacations = await vacationsLogic.getAllVacationsAsync();
    response.json(vacations);
}
catch (err) {
    response.status(500).send(err.message);
}
});
```

and here is the login router:

```
router.post("/login", async (request, response) => {
try {
    const credentials = request.body;
    const user = await authLogic.login(credentials);
    if (!user) {
        response.status(401).send("Illegal username or password");
        return
    }
    request.session.user = user;
    response.json(user);
}
catch (err) {
    response.status(500).send(err.message);
}
})
```

and here is the register router:

```
router.post("/register", async (request, response) => {
try {
    const user = new User(0, request.body.firstName, request.body.lastName, request.body.username, request.body.password, 0);
    // if username already exits - 
    // return some error(400) to the client.
    const addedUser = await authLogic.register(user);
    // Save that user in the session:
    request.session.user = addedUser;
    response.status(201).json(addedUser);
}
catch (err) {
    response.status(500).send(err.message);
}
})
```

Comment: You are trying to access login page ? Your question is not clear

Comment: @SijuSamson No, I'm trying to access another page that requires login and uses that middleware of "isLoggedIn"